# How to Use Newer Version of Library Than Stackage Resolver Has Available

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I want to use the `katip` library, version `0.5.0.0` in a `stack`-based project. (The project can be found [here](https://github.com/StevenXL/servant-persistent/tree/add-katip)).

Unfortunately, my `stack.yaml` file has the resolver `lts-6.4`which is downloading `katip-0.2.0.0`.

What is the correct way to use `katip-0.5.0.0`?

I tried modifying my `cabal` file to use `katip >= 0.5 && <0.6`, but when I did so, I got this errors:

`In the dependencies for servant-persistent-0.2.0.0:
    katip-0.2.0.0 must match >=0.5 && <0.6 (latest applicable is 0.5.0.1)`

Comment: Why do you use `lts-6.4`? With stack you must choose: either everything old or everything new... with the latter being almost always preferrable. If you want to mix old and new library dependencies, you'll need to explicitly juggle `extra-deps`, but at that point you might easier just use good old Cabal-install instead. Or rather, [good _new_ Cabal-install](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/05/announcing-cabal-new-build-nix-style-local-builds/)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1) Modify the cabal constraint to allow newer version of katib i.e:

```
katip >= 0.5 && < 0.6
```

2) Modify stack.yaml file to allow it

```
extra-deps:
- katip-0.5.0.0
```

That being said, unless you have a strong reason - it is better to always use new stackage resolver. The latest one is `lts-9.5`.

Comment: Sibi, thank you for the comment. The reason that I don't use a newer resolver is that if I do, I get more errors: `In the dependencies for servant-persistent-0.2.0.0:
    base-4.9.1.0 must match >=4.7 && <4.9 (latest applicable is 4.8.2.0)
    servant-0.11 must match >=0.7 && <0.8 (latest applicable is 0.7.1)
    servant-js-0.9.3 must match >=0.7 && <0.8 (latest applicable is 0.7.1)
    servant-server-0.11 must match >=0.7 && <0.8 (latest applicable is 0.7.1)`

Comment: @StevenL. Sounds like your cabal package has constraints that do not match , so they should be modified if you want to use them.  The packages within the resolver are all compatible with each other.

One way to quickly see if things still build when ignoring constraints is to pass `--allow-newer`, which essentially ignores constraints altogether.